# How to Automatically Make Niceframes Over Multiple Pages

Tags: page-breaking, books, page, frame

I would like to create a special component of a book in which all the pages are framed in the manner of `niceframe`. And so, I would like an entire chapter, as usual, with the usual page breaks, and have the contents of each page displayed like so:

[image]

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{niceframe}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\niceframe{\lipsum[1-6]}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I modify the above code so that, say, if the content normally extends over two pages, two pages of content would (automatically) appear, each within a `niceframe`? Similarly, for multiple pages greater than two.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `breakable tcolorbox` and define the border according to your taste.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{decorated}[1][]{%
enhanced, breakable, notitle,
sharp corners, colframe=black!10!white, colback=black!10!white,
boxsep=3mm,
overlay={
\draw[line width=1pt] ([shift={(2mm,-2mm)}]frame.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-2mm,2mm)}]frame.south east);
\draw[line width=1.5pt] ([shift={(1mm,-3mm)}]frame.north west)-|([shift={(3mm,-1mm)}]frame.north west)-|([shift={(-3mm,-3mm)}
]frame.north east)-|([shift={(-1mm,3mm)}]frame.south east)-|([shift={(-3mm,1mm)}]frame.south east)-|([shift={(3mm,3mm)}]frame.south west)-|cycle;}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{decorated}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{decorated}

\end{document}
```

[image]